# There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table in django

Tags: python, django

There are a lot of questions related to this error on SO, but either I understand each of them incorrectly, or they do not apply to this case.

I have the following code in `photo/models.py`.

```
class Photo(EmptyModelBase):
    # there's a lot of fields in this model.
```

And the following in `points/models.py`

```
class Label(EmptyModelBase):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='labels')
```

Considering this works, I understand it to mean that the `Photo` model holds an unique key, since `Label` can have a `photo` field with a foreignkey to the `Photo` model.

So, next I wanted to add another model to `points/models.py` , that also holds a foreignkey to `Photos`

```
class Material(EmptyModelBase):   
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='material')
```

When trying to add these changes to the database, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "photos_photo"
```

What I though this error meant is that the Photo model does not have an unique constraint, i.e. entries in the Photo model are not necessarily unique, therefor the foreignkey might not know which entry to use. However, I can add the foreignkey in Label to the model, so that explanation doesn't appear to make sense.

Comment: the issue is that there is no unique key present in Photo model. Do you have primary_key inside Photo model ? where have you defined EmptyModelBase , is it a abstract class ?

Comment: There is a unique key present in the `photo` model, i.e. it holds `id`. As such, I'm confused it's possible to create the foreignkey on `label` but not on `material`

Answer (score -2):

Extend your models with `django.db.models.Model` then it will have some unique field in it, say id.

Please refer to documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)

Comment: Since the `Label` class does work, doesn't that imply there's already an unique field in `Photo`? How  can `Label` work while `Material` can't?